# Creating Counts for binned data using .loc, slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I want to get 0's in one column based on np.nan in another column.
This is to allow me to get two different counts based on two different columns which have nan's in different places.
I am binning the dataframe as a whole by mean values, using binning by sum to. The below code works but the .loc lines are making it very slow for my real data.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100),
                   "b": np.random.random(100),
                   "id": np.arange(100)})

my_df['a'][23] = np.nan
my_df['b'][56] = np.nan

my_df['count_type1'] = 1
my_df['count_type2'] = 1

my_df.loc[(my_df.a.isnull()), my_df.count_type1] = 0
my_df.loc[(my_df.b.isnull()), my_df.count_type2] = 0

bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
groups = my_df.groupby(np.digitize(my_df.a, bins))

binned_data_mean = groups.mean()
binned_data_counts = groups.sum()

binned_data_mean['count_type1'] = binned_data_counts['count_type1']
binned_data_mean['count_type2'] = binned_data_counts['count_type2']
```

Is there a faster way to achve what I want?

Comment: Your code produces errors, shouldn't this be `my_df.loc[(my_df.a.isnull()), 'count_type1'] = 0
my_df.loc[(my_df.b.isnull()), 'count_type2'] = 0`? Also I get 857us using this version, if I use `where` this becomes 723us

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, it doesn't give me errors when I run it. I'll try using the while method for my own code. I was surprised at the big jump in run time when I added this line, previously all my code (approx 200 lines, although that doesn't say much) ran pretty much instantaneously, now it takes about two minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prob do something like this if you need an indicator variable.

```
In [28]: %timeit my_df['count_type1'] = my_df.a.where(my_df.a.isnull(),1).fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 611 µs per loop
```

This is even better

```
In [47]: %timeit my_df['count_type1'] = my_df.a.notnull().astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop
```